# How can I set an attribute via data binding in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to set the `checked` attribute using an `ng-repeat` as shown below:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <input type="checkbox" {{thing.is_it_checked}}>
    <div>{{thing.is_it_checked}}</div> // shows either "checked" or ""
</div>
```

I tried with without the "{{}}", but it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="thing.is_it_checked">
    <div>{{thing.is_it_checked}}</div>
</div>
```

[ngChecked](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChecked)

Answer (score 1):

[`ng-checked`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChecked) is used for that purpose.
Try `<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="thing.is_it_checked != ''">`.